# Convert string to Uint8Array in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im SOO very new to Flutter and I dont know where to begin. I need to convert a string like this
349caa523e0787003e0787033e053e08 to (what I assume is an array in flutter) to write to flutter_blue.

I need to convert it to 0x39, 0x9c,0xaa .... so that I can pass this to await d.write([0xXX, 0xXX])

I did get some help doing it Javascript eg.

```
var s = "ab05d705";
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
 result.push(parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
}

result = Uint8Array.from(result);
```

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: try this: `var list = RegExp('..')
.allMatches("ab05d705")
.map((m) => int.parse(m.group(0), radix: 16));
print(list);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something similar to your Javascript snippet:

```
var s = "ab05d705";
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
  result.add(int.parse(s.substring(i, i + 2), radix: 16));
}
```

Comment: Thank you . This is closer. I think I now need to work out how to get it into Uint8Array as I now get this error when sent to flutter_blue   ''' Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>''

Comment: you could try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html but I'm not sure what data type d.write expects

Comment: Thanks this seems to work  await _ledChar.write(result.cast<int>()); but I still need to see if its sending the correct data

Comment: Thank you all for the help . Its working . I am now starting to understand Flutter

Answer (score 2):

You can perform any of the option from below to covert it:

**Option 1:**

```
String s = new String.fromCharCodes(inputAsUint8List);
var outputAsUint8List = new Uint8List.fromList(s.codeUnits);
```

**Option 2:**

```
List<int> list = 'xxx'.codeUnits;
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
String string = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
```